# How to do Assisted Injection with Navigation Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, navigation-compose

I've a composable called `ParentScreen` and a `ViewModel` named `ParentViewModel`. Inside the `ParentViewModel`, I am collecting a value from my repo.

```kotlin
class MyRepo @Inject constructor() {
    fun getParentData() = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() // some dummy value
}

@HiltViewModel
class ParentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    myRepo: MyRepo
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _parentData = MutableStateFlow("")
    val parentData = _parentData.asStateFlow()

    init {
        val realData = myRepo.getParentData()
        _parentData.value = realData
    }
}

@Composable
fun ParentScreen(
    parentViewModel: ParentViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val parentData by parentViewModel.parentData.collectAsState()
    ChildWidget(parentData = parentData)
}
```

Inside the `ParentScreen` composable, I have a `ChildWidget` composable and it has its own `ViewModel` named `ChildViewModel`.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ChildViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val parentData: String
) : ViewModel() {

    @AssistedFactory
    interface ChildViewModelFactory {
        fun create(parentData: String): ChildViewModel
    }

    init {
        Timber.d("Child says data is $parentData ")
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildWidget(
    parentData: String,
    childViewModel: ChildViewModel = hiltViewModel() // How do I supply assisted injection factory here?
) {
    // Code omitted
}
```

Now, I want to get `parentData` inside `ChildViewModel`'s constructor.

**Questions**

- How do I supply `ChildViewModelFactory` to Navigation Compose's `hiltViewModel` method?
- If that's not possible, what would be the most suitable method to inject an object from the parent composable to the child composable's `ViewModel`? How about creating a `lateinit` property and `init` method like below?

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ChildViewModel @Inject constructor(
) : ViewModel() {
    lateinit var parentData: Long

    fun init(parentData: Long){
        if(this::parentData.isInitialized) return
        this.parentData = parentData
    }
}
```

Comment: I would really love to learn from the answers to come. Personally, I started with Compose in my recent project, and I found that keeping one ViewModel at the parent level it a lot easier. If there is any data in the child composable and want to past it pack to the parent, I just return the same with a Unit type parameters. I am not sure, if my way is the right one, I would love to see the answers to come.

Comment: @Abdullah in this case you can up-vote this question and **Follow** for updates, commenting won't subscribe you to answers.

Comment: Missed that .

Answer (score 8):

You can do this using `EntryPointAccessors` (from Hilt) and a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` from View Model library.

In my [sample app](https://github.com/nglauber/books_compose/), `BookFormScreen` is using `BookFormViewModel` and the view model needs to load a book based on a `bookId` passed by the previous screen. This is what I did:

```kotlin
class BookFormViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    ...
    @Assisted private val bookId: String?,
) : ViewModel() {

    ...

    @AssistedFactory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(bookId: String?): BookFormViewModel
    }

    companion object {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        fun provideFactory(
            assistedFactory: Factory, // this is the Factory interface 
                                      // declared above
            bookId: String?
        ): ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return assistedFactory.create(bookId) as T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm not using `@HiltViewModel`. The `provideFactory` will be use to supply a factory to create this view model.

Then, define the `ViewModelFactoryProvider` for the entry point:

```kotlin
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
interface ViewModelFactoryProvider {

    fun bookDetailsViewModelFactory(): BookDetailsViewModel.Factory

    fun bookFormViewModelFactory(): BookFormViewModel.Factory
}
```

Now, you need to define a composable function to provide the view model using this factory.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun bookFormViewModel(bookId: String?): BookFormViewModel {
    val factory = EntryPointAccessors.fromActivity(
        LocalContext.current as Activity,
        ViewModelFactoryProvider::class.java
    ).bookFormViewModelFactory()

    return viewModel(factory = BookFormViewModel.provideFactory(factory, bookId))
}
```

If you're using the navigation library, you can add the `ViewModelStoreOwner` parameter in this function and use it in `viewModel()` function call. For this parameter, you can pass the `NavBackStackEntry` object, with this, the view model will be scoped to that particular back stack entry.

Finally, you can use your view model in your composable.

```kotlin
val bookFormViewModel: BookFormViewModel = bookFormViewModel(bookId)
```

Comment: I'm getting a error: `.Factory cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method`... I can't spot what I'm doing differently to your sample project? (Which is awesome by the way, thanks for sharing!) Any ideas?

Comment: hi Will. You probably figured it out already, but seems like you are not declaring the `EntryPoint` which you provide the reference to the `YourClass.Factory` instance.

Comment: I think I've got that with `@EntryPoint @InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class) interface ViewModelFactoryProvider { ... }`. Do I need to do anything else with this other than declare it?

Comment: A hero among men!